# Magento manipulate weight on checkout

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I have simple products in Magento 1.9 that I can combine ship and would like to change the total shipping weight at checkout (and in shopping cart view for shipping estimate calculation etc) based on sku. For example, if one or two widgets with the correct sku are purchased, their weight is 1 lbs combined. If three to five widgets with the correct sku are purchased, their weight is 2 lbs combined etc. Tablerates could handle this if all items were included. However, I must limit it to certain items determined by sku.

So currently in Magento, each item has a weight of 1 lbs and total weight is `number of items * 1 lbs`. I have found answers to display total weight, or update the item's weight in the database, but nothing that fulfills these requirements. I'm very new to Magento and am struggling to achieve this. If you reply back with suggested code changes, could you please be specific as to the file's location that should be edited?

**Edit**

Following Mladen Ilić's suggestions, I have come up with the follow code that calculates the total weight on the event sales_quote_collect_totals_after event. **How do I send the new adjusted weight to Magneto to use it through checkout?**

/app/etc/modules/Weight_Extension.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Weight_Extension>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <active>true</active>
        </Weight_Extension>
    </modules>
</config>
```

/app/code/locale/Weight/Extension/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Weight_Extension>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Weight_Extension>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <weight_extension>
                <class>Weight_Extension_Model</class>
            </weight_extension>
        </models>
        <events>
            <sales_quote_collect_totals_after>
                <observers>
                    <weight_extension>
                        <class>weight_extension/observer</class>
                        <method>adjustTotalWeight</method>
                    </weight_extension>
                </observers>
            </sales_quote_collect_totals_after>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

/app/code/locale/Weight/Extension/Model

```
<?php 
class Weight_Extension_Model_Observer
{
    public function adjustTotalWeight($observer) 
    {
        $items = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllItems();

        $combinedItems = 0;
        foreach($items as $item)
        {
            if($item->getSku() == 1 || $item->getSku() == 2)
            {
                 $combinedItems++;
            }
        }

        if($combinedItems > 0 && $combinedItems < 3)
            $weight = 1;
        if($combinedItems >= 3 && $combinedItems < 6)
            $weight = 2;

        //send new $weight to Magento and persist through checkout?
    } 
}
```

How do I send the new adjusted weight to Magneto to use it through checkout?

Answer (score 0):

Magento calculates weight used for getting shipping rates in `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Shipping::collect`.

When collecting shipping address totals, items are looped and their weight accumulated and then set to address object.

That being said, you have to be careful how are you going to change this behavior. On a first look, it seems that using `sales_quote_collect_totals_after` event could be the right way.

When event is triggered get all shipping address items, loop through them and use custom logic for calculating weight.

Best of luck.

Comment: I believe the sales_quote_collect_totals_after event would be added to the config.xml file? I see a few config.xml files. Which is the correct location of that file?

Second, I believe a new observer must be added that the event will call. What is the location that custom model observers should be added to?

Comment: https://www.atwix.com/magento/overriding-observers/ - Random google result. I'm in no way affiliated with author. Just the first part how to set up observer, ignore the part about overriding it.

Comment: Thanks Mladen. I can create a new total weight. However, I don't know how to tell Magneto to use the new weight for checkout. I've updated my code in my original post.

Comment: You should set newly calculated weight on shipping address object. You already used session to fetch customer's quote. Now use that quote to get shipping address - `$quote->getShippingAddress()->setWeight($weight)`.

Comment: Is there documentation on the various properties of $quote (and other such objects?)

Comment: Sadly, there's no real documentation – One think you should have in mind is that Magento models often use `__call` magic method for manipulating models internal data. You should check `Varien_Object` for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You writted event in *adminhtml* context, you have to change it to *frontend*.

Comment: Hi Soul. I have the observer firing and creating a new weight. But I don't know how to send the new weight to Magento so it can be used through checkout. I've updated my code in the original post.

Comment: You should observe *sales_quote_collect_totals_before* event. In your loop, you can set weight to 0 *$item->setWeight(0);*
And put your calculated weight on the last item.

Comment: Thanks @Soul. That worked. Where is documentation for all the available events and various functions within magento? I can only find REST and SOAP API documentation [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/) which isn't helpful for making custom observers.

Comment: You can use this snippet : https://gist.github.com/AurelienLavorel/dbe4bf183b6d2a8c48730f2c3aadcc00